# Not Able to Pass Parameter inside an Object

Tags: javascript

Passing an RGB color inside a constructor like `new Color([0, 0, 255])` works fine but I need to update the RGB based on usere select so I tried to achieve this dynamically like

```
 var color = '0, 0, 255';

 config.symbolTraceNetworkEdges = new 
 SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, 
 new Color([color]), 10);
```

I am not getting any error but no color rendering as the the RGB return `nan` on `console.log(config.symbolTraceNetworkEdges);`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`['0, 0, 255']` is not the same as `[0, 0, 255]`

It seems you should split your string and convert into numbers

```
var color = '0, 0, 255'
var parseColor = function(str) {
  return parseInt(str, 10)
}
new Color(color.split(',').map(parseColor), 10)
```

Though I'm not 100% sure because you haven't specified what `Color` is and how it was implemented.